# browse for files from a machine

Tags: netbeans

is there a way i can implement a browse function in NetBeans 6.5 by use of a button and a text field? i want when i click on the button to be able to browse different drives for files and when i click open the file name plus location appears on the text field the way we browse for files in windows.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just add an event listener to the button and show a file selection dialog box inside the listener's method.